Python, a method that is always executed before other methods in an instance of the class
I want to make it so that before executing the method of the class instance, another mandatory method was carried out:
class Example:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def method_before(self):
        print(f"x = {self.x}, y = {self.y}")

    def sum_numbers(self):
        self.method_before()
        print(self.x + self.y)

    def mult_numbers(self):
        self.method_before()
        print(self.x * self.y)


test_instance = Example(x=10, y=2)
test_instance.sum_numbers()

This is simplified example. How can I make the method method_before() run automatically without explicitly specifying it in other methods? Thank you if you share the ways

If there were a feature for this, it would have way too many messy implications. Running before __init__, for example, when none of the stuff it depends on is initialized.

A decorator might be better, as it would be explicit. Note that __init__ is also a method, but it would not make sense to run method_before  there... :D

It would help, also, to tell us why you need such a thing. Knowing what you're really trying to achieve will help guide you towards an appropriate solution.

You could maybe try hooking into __getattribute__, but that won't get you all the way there.

So you want some kind of AOP in Python?

Here are three potential paths forward. Unfortunately, none of them are completely free of "additional specifications". Note I renamed method_before() to flag it as "non-public" and make excluding it with the dunder methods more convenient.
Conventional Decorator:
class Example():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @staticmethod
    def _method_before(f):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print(f"x = {self.x}, y = {self.y}")
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    @_method_before
    def sum_numbers(self):
        print(self.x + self.y)

    @_method_before
    def mult_numbers(self, z):
        print(self.x * self.y * z)

Post Definition Decorator:
class Example():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @staticmethod
    def _method_before(f):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print(f"x = {self.x}, y = {self.y}")
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    def sum_numbers(self):
        print(self.x + self.y)

    def mult_numbers(self, z):
        print(self.x * self.y * z)

method_list = [f for f in dir(Example) if callable(getattr(Example, f)) and not f.startswith("_")]
for m in method_list:
    setattr(Example, m, getattr(Example, "_method_before")(getattr(Example, m)))

MetaClass:
class Example_Meta(type):
    def __init__(self, name, bases, dict):
        method_list = [f for f in dir(self) if callable(getattr(self, f)) and not f.startswith("_")]
        for m in method_list:
            setattr(self, m, getattr(self, "_method_before")(getattr(self, m)))

class Example(metaclass=Example_Meta):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @staticmethod
    def _method_before(f):
        def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print(f"x = {self.x}, y = {self.y}")
            return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper

    def sum_numbers(self):
        print(self.x + self.y)

    def mult_numbers(self, z):
        print(self.x * self.y * z)

All versions should allow you to do:
foo = Example(1, 2)
foo.sum_numbers()
foo.mult_numbers(10)

x = 1, y = 2
3
x = 1, y = 2
20

